# MySQL - using the value of one field to target another field by name

Tags: mysql, variables, if-statement

Table User contains the fields id, name, fruit, veggies, meat.
Table FruitType contains the fields id, type, healthy, user.
Let's presume the table User looks like this:

1, Marvin, Apple, Carrot, Pork
2, Zorlax, Blueberry, Lettuce, Lamb

.. while the FruitType table looks like this:

1, fruit, yes, 1
2, veggies, yes, 2

What I would like is to be able to JOIN them, and search for a value in Users, in a specific field, depending on the VALUE from the "type" field in FruitType. For example, I would like to be able to do this:

```
SELECT User.'type' FROM User 

LEFT JOIN FruitType ft ON (ft.user = User.id) etc.. conditions and so on...
```

Basically, I want the 'type' part to take the value of the 'type' field in the FruitType table. Something like a field variable, in essence.

I hope I'm being clear enough. Here is a real example I'm working on right now, in case this seems too confusing, although the real one might do even more damage:

```
  IF (trigger_by_date IS NOT NULL,
  date_add(books.trigger_by_date, INTERVAL trigger_by_date_add DAY),
  date_add(trigger_step_created_at, INTERVAL trigger_by_step_add DAY))
  as deadline
```

In this case, trigger_by_date is the variable. If it's not null, simply use its value as the field identifier.

Edit:

For clarity's sake: there is no "type" column in User. The "type" in the example query should be replaced by the actual value of type in the FruitType table. So if a condition yielded the result FruitType.type = fruit, I want the query to SELECT User.fruit. If a condition gave FruitType.type = veggies, I want the query to SELECT User.veggies. I hope it is clearer now. I basically want the field I am selecting to depend on the type in FruitType.

Comment: Ended up restructuring their entire database to make this problem go away. In the end, it turned out to be much easier and about 4000% faster. Thanks for trying though. If any future reader finds a solution, don't hesitate to contact me directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was rewriting the query with a couple of advanced subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is very confusing. In the code snippet you posted, you wrote "... User.'type' From User" while in the description, you say there isn't type field in User table. Still, my guess is that you are trying to fetch 'type' field from FruitType table.

Probably this is what you are looking for
    SELECT FruitType.type From FruitType ft JOIN User ON (ft.type=User.id)

Comment: I knew it would be, sorry about that. Let me try again, will modify the original post

Comment: Clarity through shortening your post :)